# How can I quantify the difference between these plots in R?

Tags: r

I have four barplots. Three of them have similar patterns but one behaves differently. How can I show this difference in R?  As you can see I've used colored-coded arrows, but I like to quantify the similarity between the three plots and their difference from the fourth.
[image]
Thanks for any help.
Here is my data:

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Gene.name = c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", 
"Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", 
"Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", 
"Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", 
"Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", 
"Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", "Gene3", 
"Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", 
"Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", 
"Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", "Gene4", 
"Gene4", "Gene4"), Cancer.Study = c("Stomach Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Stomach Adenocarcinoma ", "Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", 
"Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", 
"Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", "Esophageal Carcinoma ", "Esophageal Carcinoma ", 
"Lung Adenocarcinoma ", "Lung Adenocarcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", 
"Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", 
"Kidney Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma ", "Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", 
"Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", "Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", "Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma ", 
"Glioblastoma Multiforme ", "Esophageal Carcinoma", "Esophageal Carcinoma", 
"Esophageal Carcinoma", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma", 
"Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma", 
"Breast Invasive Carcinoma", "Breast Invasive Carcinoma", "Breast Invasive Carcinoma", 
"Breast Invasive Carcinoma", "Stomach Adenocarcinoma", "Stomach Adenocarcinoma", 
"Stomach Adenocarcinoma", "Lung Adenocarcinoma", "Lung Adenocarcinoma", 
"Lung Adenocarcinoma", "Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma", "Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma", 
"Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma", "Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma", 
"Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma", "Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma", 
"Prostate Adenocarcinoma", "Prostate Adenocarcinoma", "Prostate Adenocarcinoma", 
"Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma", "Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma", 
"Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma", 
"Colorectal Adenocarcinoma", "Kidney Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", 
"Kidney Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma", "Glioblastoma Multiforme", 
"Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", "Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", 
"Esophageal Carcinoma ", "Esophageal Carcinoma ", "Lung Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Lung Adenocarcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", 
"Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", "Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", 
"Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", "Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", 
"Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Stomach Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", "Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", "Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma ", 
"Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma ", "Glioblastoma Multiforme ", 
"Glioblastoma Multiforme ", "Kidney Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma ", 
"Esophageal Carcinoma ", "Esophageal Carcinoma ", "Stomach Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Stomach Adenocarcinoma ", "Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", 
"Uterine Corpus Endometrial Carcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", 
"Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", "Liver Hepatocellular Carcinoma ", 
"Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", "Bladder Urothelial Carcinoma ", 
"Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", "Colorectal Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", "Breast Invasive Carcinoma ", "Lung Adenocarcinoma ", 
"Lung Adenocarcinoma ", "Kidney Renal Clear Cell Carcinoma ", 
"Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", "Prostate Adenocarcinoma ", "Glioblastoma Multiforme ", 
"Lung Squamous Cell Carcinoma "), Alteration.Frequency = c(1.046025105, 
3.347280335, 2.018348624, 0.733944954, 0.161550889, 0.161550889, 
1.453957997, 1.000909918, 0.727934486, 1.081081081, 0.540540541, 
0.968992248, 0.581395349, 0.265251989, 0.265251989, 0.795755968, 
1.31826742, 0.97323601, 0.243309002, 0.400801603, 0.200400802, 
0.399201597, 0.336700337, 0.540540541, 16.75675676, 2.162162162, 
0.265251989, 0.265251989, 15.64986737, 0.530503979, 0.090991811, 
0.454959054, 14.83166515, 0.727934486, 0.627615063, 6.694560669, 
4.184100418, 0.19379845, 6.395348837, 1.356589147, 0.199600798, 
7.185628743, 0.199600798, 0.550458716, 4.403669725, 2.018348624, 
0.801603206, 5.410821643, 0.200400802, 0.243309002, 5.109489051, 
0.729927007, 4.684975767, 0.484652666, 0.753295669, 1.129943503, 
1.01010101, 3.119266055, 2.018348624, 1.621621622, 1.081081081, 
0.968992248, 0.775193798, 0.265251989, 0.265251989, 1.061007958, 
1.18289354, 0.363967243, 0.97323601, 0.486618005, 0.161550889, 
0.161550889, 0.969305331, 1.255230126, 0.400801603, 0.400801603, 
0.199600798, 0.598802395, 0.505050505, 0.168350168, 0.564971751, 
1.081081081, 2.702702703, 1.046025105, 2.30125523, 1.651376147, 
1.100917431, 0.265251989, 0.265251989, 1.591511936, 0.97323601, 
0.486618005, 0.161550889, 0.161550889, 0.969305331, 0.818926297, 
0.363967243, 0.968992248, 0.19379845, 1.129943503, 0.400801603, 
0.200400802, 0.336700337, 0.199600798), Alteration.Type = c("amp", 
"mutated", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", 
"mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "amp", 
"mutated", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "mutated", 
"mutated", "amp", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "multiple", "homdel", 
"amp", "mutated", "multiple", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", 
"amp", "mutated", "multiple", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "amp", 
"mutated", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", 
"homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", 
"amp", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", 
"homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", 
"homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "homdel", "mutated", "amp", 
"mutated", "amp", "mutated", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", 
"mutated", "amp", "mutated", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", 
"mutated", "homdel", "amp", "mutated", "amp", "mutated", "amp", 
"mutated", "mutated", "homdel", "mutated", "amp", "mutated")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-104L))
```

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I show this...`? Show how? Graphically? Numerically? Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the quantification of the difference In Gene2's variant type composition compared to other genes I think @tpetzoldt answer utilizing `vegdist` is helpful.
But for the visualization part:

1. as you want to be able to compare Genes so it's better to show them beside each other
2. geom_point plots are more suitable for 2d plots where both x and y axis are continuous or numerical. here I prefer geom_bar
3. the Cancer.Study labels have long strings and high number of categories. better to place them in x axis and rotate them.
   Considering all the points mentioned I recommend the following plot

```
df$Cancer.Study=trimws(df$Cancer.Study)
ggplot(df,aes(y=Alteration.Frequency,x=Gene.name, fill=Gene.name)) + coord_flip()+
    geom_bar(position="dodge",stat = 'identity') +
    facet_grid(Cancer.Study ~ Alteration.Type, scales = "free_x", switch = 'y') + theme_bw() +
    theme(strip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0),
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image: gridplot]
here `coord_flip()` flips x & y axis of the plot. `scales = "free_x"` gives the x axis the freedom to have different scales for each group. `switch = 'y'` moves the cancer type labels from right to left. `trip.text.y.left = element_text(angle = 0)` makes the cancer type labels horizontal.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to still use a graph, but one where the comparison is easier, you could try separating the alteration types (**edit**: you have some trailing white spaces in your cancer study column which creates seemingly distinct categories)

```
library(ggplot2)

df$Cancer.Study=trimws(df$Cancer.Study)

ggplot(df,aes(y=Alteration.Frequency,x=Cancer.Study,color=Gene.name)) +
  geom_point() + geom_jitter() +
  facet_wrap(~Alteration.Type,ncol=1) + theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60,hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Some of the cancer types in the X-axis are duplicated, How to fix it?

Comment: This question goes back to the OP. How to you want to aggregate the duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

Configuring the faceted graph above like this could also help highlight the effect on "Gene2" with Alteration type "amp":

```
cancer_test <- cancer %>%
group_by(Cancer.Study) 
ggplot(cancer_test, mapping = aes(x = Cancer.Study, y = Alteration.Frequency, color = Alteration.Type)) + geom_jitter() + facet_wrap(~Gene.name, ncol=1) + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A numerical comparison can be done with dissimilarity indices like Chisquare or Bray-Curtis (see below), but before doing this, we can first visualize association between gene and study as a heatmap. Here we first need to convert the tidy data format (that is of course a good idea) into a cross table.

The following approach uses `pivot_wider` from **tidyr** for the crosstable. For plotting the heatmap we can use package **pheatmap** (pretty heatmap). As the data types from a tidyverse pipe are not 100% compatible to `pheatmap`, we may convert it to a standard `data.frame` and then assign the names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(vegan)
library(pheatmap)

## re-arrange as crosstable
crosstable <- 
  df %>% 
    mutate(Cancer.Study = sub(" $", "", Cancer.Study)) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Gene.name, Alteration.Type),
                names_from = Cancer.Study, 
                values_from = Alteration.Frequency)

## show the result
crosstable

## convert to standard data frame, because tibbles don't support row names
crosstable <- as.data.frame(crosstable)

## assign row names and remove the ID columns
rownames(crosstable) <- with(crosstable, paste(Gene.name, Alteration.Type))
crosstable <- crosstable[,-c(1, 2)]

## visualize crosstable as a heatmap with a cluster analysis
pheatmap(crosstable)
```

[image: Heatmap]

If we want to analyze the **differences** between "the plots"  (i.e. the genes) numerically we can make another cross table, where the genes are the rows and the studies with their mutations are the variables:

```r
crosstable2 <- 
  df %>% 
    mutate(Cancer.Study = sub(" $", "", Cancer.Study)) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = Gene.name, 
                names_from = c(Cancer.Study, Alteration.Type),
                values_from = Alteration.Frequency) %>%
    data.frame()

## assign row names and remove the ID column
rownames(crosstable2) <- crosstable2$Gene.name
crosstable2 <- crosstable2[,-1]

## high values of d mean high dissimilarity
d <- as.matrix(vegdist(crosstable2, method="bray", na.rm=TRUE))

print(d)      # numerical dissimilarity
#          Gene1     Gene2     Gene3     Gene4
# Gene1 0.0000000 0.6842561 0.1929800 0.1767879
# Gene2 0.6842561 0.0000000 0.6868717 0.6873556
# Gene3 0.1929800 0.6868717 0.0000000 0.2085860
# Gene4 0.1767879 0.6873556 0.2085860 0.0000000

pheatmap(d)   # visualization
```

[image: dissimilarity between genes]

**Edits / Notes**

- removed trailing whitespaces from `Cancer.Study` variable (thanks to @user2974951 for spotting this)
- added heatmap to vizualize data
- add second approach with dissimilarity between genes